# LocationFusedAPI setMaxWaitTime works only once

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, google-location-services, fusedlocationproviderclient

I've a simple app with LocationFused API implementation:

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest(), pi);
}

protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(60000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}
```

When the app is deployed on a device, I should expect to receive a batch of locations every 60 seconds as specified in setMaxWaitTime method but this happens only the first time after deploy (I received 7 locations after 1 minute), then I start receiving 1 location every 5 seconds.

Why setMaxWaitTime works only once?

Comment: If the wait time is smaller than the interval requested with setInterval(long), then the interval will be used instead.

Comment: @JaiminSarvan this is not the case because interval time is 5 seconds and wait time is 1 minute. Please read the question before answering.

Comment: This is not the answer only comment